Joining a big company that has recently fired many employees
I worked for one MNC after my graduation (PhD in chemistry) for 1 year

then joined a start up with good hike in salary. Although my new job is good and I have got a senior level position

after 4 months of my joining in my new company I got a call from another big MNC with a more lucrative position and even more hike in the salary


Although, the offer seems lucrative - I am unable to take any decision due to the following reasons :

The last company has recently fired many of its employees

I would be switching 3 jobs within the first 1.5 years of my career



Can anyone please put some general advice regarding that. I know that specific advices cannot be given without much information about the scenario.


The experience of being in a start-up (or other small company) is often very different from being in a very large company.  Do you have a preference?  (If you prefer small companies, then staying where you are would clearly be better; OTOH, if you much prefer bigger companies, then that might give you a reason you can tell potential future employers as to why you jumped ship so soon.)

Why would your current company retain if they know that you are redundant? Job-insecurities are there every where

Is MNC short for multinational company?

@Anketam Yes it is

If you have a job offer in hand, for a significant further increase in salary, then I think that most top-level professionals would take that better job offer.  The short tenure shouldn't be an issue; it's a sign that you're in high demand. Obviously it wasn't an issue for your next employer, and that's the only thing that counts.
That said, if you think there's a bad smell about the recent layoffs, do your due diligence, and ask some tough questions in the interviews. It's true that you don't want to get into some death-march situation that's been left behind.

Thank you. It is a very reasonable advice


The last company has recently fired many of its employees

Which employees?  If they laid off positions for the tasks that you do there is reason for concern.  If they laid off people in other departments there may not be.  Perhaps manufacturing was shipped to another country; or, accounting has been outsourced.  Those kind of things are of no concern.
If they were from the chemical engineering department you should ask your interviewer "why".  Also you should do your own research.

I would be switching 3 jobs within the first 1.5 years of my career

You will probably be asked about this, and you should have an accurate answer.  Something like:  "Each time I moved, my responsibilities and salary increased a significant amount".  Should be perfectly reasonable.
Given that you were in a startup, it would also be acceptable to say something like "I felt the company was on the brink of failure".  If this is true, it would also be perfectly acceptable.
Consider your two concerns.  They are identical except from the point of view.  You are concerned why the company laid off a bunch of people.  They might be concerned that you shifted jobs frequently.  There are good and bad responses to both concerns by each party.
If your interviewer becomes defensive about his company's layoffs, and chides you for changing jobs then you have gained valuable information.  This is an indication of a company that expects far more from you then it is willing to give.
If they accept your reasons for job hopping as good.  Then indicate a good and clear reason for laying off/firing employees, and if they were treated fairly, they are probably a good employer.

Yes, I asked one of my friends (who is also an employee of this company) about the recent layoffs. She just told me "It happens sometimes you know !" I don't know what I can make out of what she said, but I will definitely enquire more

As past answers have said, job - hopping is not viewed positively. The assumption is that you won't stay with this job either, and therefore are not worth hiring. I strongly suggest that you stay for at least a year, preferably two, before looking elsewhere unless the current job becomes untenable for some reason.

If they didn't think OP was worth hiring, they wouldn't have made the offer. Since they did, it's evidently not an issue.
